# Symfony2 PUGXAutoCompleterBundle Error: no object

Tags: php, symfony, autocomplete, bundle

I have problem with bundle `PUGXAutoCompleterBundle`.

Error:

> Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

And my code:

DefaultController:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/autocomplete-test/search", name="autocomplete_test_search")
     */
    public function autocompleteTestSearchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->get('term');
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeAdminBundle:BrandDevice');
        $brands = $repo->findLikeName($q);
        $results = array();
        foreach($brands as $brand)
        {
            $results[] = array('id'=>$brand->getId(),'name'=>$brand->getName(),'label'=>$brand->getName());
        }
        return new JsonResponse($results);
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/autocomplete-test/{id}", name="autocomplete_test_get")
     */
    public function autocompleteTestGetAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeAdminBundle:BrandDevice');
        $brand = $em->find($id);

        return new Response($brand->getName());
    }

}
```

BrandDevice.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * BrandDevice
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="brand_device")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BrandDevice
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Te pole jest wymagane")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="logo", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="website", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Te pole jest wymagane")
     * @Assert\Url(message="Proszę podać poprawny adres strony www")
     */
    private $website;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return BrandDevice
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return BrandDevice
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set logo
     *
     * @param string $logo
     * @return BrandDevice
     */
    public function setLogo($logo)
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    /**
     * Set website
     *
     * @param string $website
     * @return BrandDevice
     */
    public function setWebsite($website)
    {
        $this->website = $website;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get website
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getWebsite()
    {
        return $this->website;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


}
```

CompanyController.php method create:

```
/**
     * @Route("/company/create", name="admin_company_create")
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $company = new Company();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($company)
            ->add('email','text',array('label'=>'Email'))
            ->add('name','text',array('label'=>'Nazwa'))
            ->add('street','text',array('label'=>'Ulica'))
            ->add('city','autocomplete',array('label'=>'Miasto','class'=>'Acme\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\BrandDevice'))
            ->add('state','choice',array('label'=>'Województwo','choices'=>array('Dolnośląskie','Opolskie')))
            ->add('zipcode','text',array('label'=>'Kod pocztowy'))
            ->add('phone','text',array('label'=>'Telefon'))
            ->add('nip','text',array('label'=>'NIP'))
            ->add('website','text',array('label'=>'Website'))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Zapisz'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $company->setDateAdd(new \DateTime());
            $company->setDateUpdate(new \DateTime());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($company);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success','Dodano firmę');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_company_edit',array('id'=>$company->getId()));
        }
        //title
        $this->view_data['title']['subheader'] = 'Dodaj';
        $this->view_data['form'] = $form->createView();
        return $this->render('AcmeAdminBundle:Company:create.html.twig', $this->view_data);
    }
```

AND view: create.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AcmeAdminBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- general form elements -->
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Dodaj firmę</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
                <div class="box-body">

                    {{ form_start(form)  }}
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.email.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.email, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.email) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.name.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.name, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.name) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.street.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.street, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.street, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.street) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.city.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.city, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.city, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.city) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.state.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.state, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.state, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.state) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.zipcode.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.zipcode, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.zipcode, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.zipcode) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.phone.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.phone, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.phone, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.phone) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.nip.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.nip, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.nip, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.nip) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {% if form.website.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        {{ form_label(form.website, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.website, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.website) }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="box-footer">
                    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}})  }}
                </div>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#form_city').autocompleter({url_list: '/autocomplete_test_search', url_get: '/autocomplete_test_get/'});
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Where is error?

Comment: Try debugging your query defined in `BrandDevice` repository to see exactly what you pass to your database. It seems that you're trying to iterate over empty result.

Comment: Could you show us `findLikeName` code?

Comment: `public function findLikeName($term)
    {
        $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $result = $qb->select('n')->from('AcmeAdminBundle:BrandDevice', 'n')
            ->where( $qb->expr()->like('n.name', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $term . '%')) )
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        return $result;
    }`